# Node js memory heap out on file upload

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to upload a file sized 200MB using angular5 node js. Every time the app crashed with following error.

```
==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x2c3a92b25ee1 <JSObject>
2: SimpleSlice(aka SimpleSlice) [native array.js:1] [bytecode=0x2c3aa14ed689 offset=41](this=0x2c3ad9b02311 <undefined>,p=0x2c3a51d2e961 <Uint8Array map = 0x2c3ad7ec1d91>,O=0,P=217330529,Q=217330529,R=0x2c3a51d6bce1 <JSArray[217330529]>)
4: ArraySliceFallback [native array.js:1] [bytecode=0x2c3aa14ed021 offset=281](this=0x2c3a51d2e961 <Uint8Array map = 0x2c3ad7ec1d91>,at=0,au=0x2c3ad9b02...

FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
4: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary, v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary>, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
5: v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary, v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::Add(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, int*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::DictionaryElementsAccessor::AddImpl(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, unsigned int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
7: v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::ShouldThrow) [/usr/local/bin/node]
8: v8::internal::JSObject::DefineOwnPropertyIgnoreAttributes(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::JSObject::AccessorInfoHandling) [/usr/local/bin/node]
9: v8::internal::JSObject::CreateDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::ShouldThrow) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::Runtime_CreateDataProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x12f2c16c6838
```

I have tried different techniques but all in vein.

```
--max-old-space-size=80896  --trace-gc-verbose

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '8096mb'}));
```

In activity monitoring when `node` grab more than 1GB the crash happen.
My development environment is mac with 8 GB ram.

Comment: From the stack trace it seems like when node tries to add a data element to a hashmap, it fails. Is it possible that this might be happening because of some fixed size of collections in javascript? And your object is exceeding that

Comment: node has a 1.4gb memory limit from v8

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-memory-limit-on-a-node-process

Comment: for a file upload, you should be using streams instead of loading it into memory - one example: https://gist.github.com/schempy/0fe3abab3d834c94b3be - google has other examples

Comment: @Robbie the issue is resolved by using streams.